# How can i make smooth scrolling in a absolut element with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i added smooth scrolling in my website, but apparently it does just work in one pagers. How can i fix it,so it works in a absolut position element, which is scrollable? Link from my website and the javascript file.

```
    $('a[href^=#]').on('click', function(e){
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop:$(href).offset().top
  },'slow');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved my problem. I just used a plugin called scrollTo:

https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

After all the solution was pretty simple.